# convertir una frase a espacio

Tags: c

yo con un amigo estuvimos tratando de resolver el siguiente código, el ejercicio que nos pidieron hacer es este

Crear un función convertirEspaciado(), que reciba como parámetro un texto y devuelve una cadena con un espacio adicional tras cada letra. Por ejemplo, “Hola, tú” devolverá “H o l a , t ú “. Crea un programa principal donde se llame a dicha función.

este fue el código que por ahora anduvimos probando

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void convertirEspaciado(char texto[])
{
    int i;
    char charSpaceTexto[strlen(texto) + 1];
    
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(texto); i++)
    {
        charSpaceTexto[i] = texto[i];
    }
    
    charSpaceTexto[strlen(texto)] = '\0';
    
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(texto); i++)
    {
        charSpaceTexto[i + 1] = ' ';
    }
    
    printf("%s\n", charSpaceTexto);
}

int main()
{
    char texto[100];
    printf("Ingrese texto a convertir: ");
    fgets(texto, 100, stdin);
    
    convertirEspaciado(texto);
    
    return 0;
}
```

el único problema, es que al momento de imprimirlo en el programiz C, en vez de que nos imprima "h o l a, t u" al momento de escribir "hola tu" nos imprime "h     @" así tal cual

que estaríamos haciendo mal?

espero alguna respuesta muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, reemplazá el título de tu pregunta. Leyéndolo tal cual, suena a que estás queriendo reemplazar toda una cadena por espacios. Lo que más bien quisiste decir es que se busca agregar espacios entre caracteres (omitiendo a los caracteres que de por sí ya son espacios).

Comment: ninguna de tus variables esta inicializada.. por lo tanto tienen cualquier valor... apuesto que si lo corres en un par de horas, en lugar de @ aparece ?...

Comment: Se supone que el tamaño de _charSpaceTexto_ no debe ser igual al de _texto_, sino mucho mayor, porque según tu ejemplo, _a cada caracter le va a suceder un espacio_.

Comment: Cómo máximo, el string espaciado debería medir el doble del original.

Answer (score 0):

El segundo ciclo reemplaza todos los caracteres excepto el primero por espacios, incluso el caracter nulo:

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(texto); i++)
{
    charSpaceTexto[i + 1] = ' ';
}
```

Al no estar terminado como corresponde, `printf` sigue imprimiendo caracteres hasta encontrar un byte 0 en la memoria.

---

Teniendo en cuenta que la cadena espaciada puede ser hasta el doble del tamaño original, puedes seguir la siguiente lógica:

- Leer un caracter de la cadena original.
- Copiar el caracter a la cadena nueva.
- Si no es un espacio, agregar uno a la cadena nueva.
- Repetir.

En código quedaría así:

```
void convertirEspaciado(char texto[])
{
    int j = 0;
    int size = strlen(texto);
    
    char spaceTexto[size * 2 + 1];
   
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        spaceTexto[j++] = texto[i];
        if (texto[i]) != ' ')
            spaceTexto[j++] = ' ';
    }
    spaceTexto[j] = 0;
    
    printf("%s\n", spaceTexto);
}
```

Comment: Faltó el punto y coma en la condición. `if (texto[i]) != ' ')` ... dessa forma `if (texto[i] != ' ');`

Comment: @cardosource así funciona bien

Comment: muchísimas gracias chicos, de hecho, pudimos resolver esto, que no pude revisar mi cuenta de stack overflow,se los agradezco de corazón gracias gracias gracias.